# Rxjs do a job after multiple observables has completed

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have 3 observables `job1()`, `job2()`, and `job3()`. I would like to call the `finalJob()` after all these 3 jobs has completed as the `finalJob()` is dependent on all 3 jobs. From what I know, I can achieve this by using `Observable.forkJoin()` like below:

```
forkJoin([this.job1(), this.job2(), this.job3()])
.subscribe(([result1, result2, result3]) => {.
    this.job1Completed = true;
    this.job2Completed = true;
    this.job3Completed = true;
    this.finalJob();
});
```

But the thing is I would like to run these 3 jobs simultaneously, so that each of these jobs can set their own completion status right after it has completed it's job, rather than waiting for another 2 jobs to complete then set the completion status all together, like below:

```
this.job1().subscribe((result1) => this.jodb1Completed = true);
this.job2().subscribe((result2) => this.jodb2Completed = true);
this.job3().subscribe((result3) => this.jodb3Completed = true);

finalJob(); // this has no guarantee all 3 jobs has completed
```

With the implementation above, I will not be able to call the `finalJob()` after all 3 jobs has completed. Is there any way to emit an event to call the `finalJob()` once all jobs has done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rxjs `tap` operator

```
forkJoin([
  this.job1().pipe(tap((result1) => this.jodb1Completed = true)),
  this.job2().pipe(tap((result2) => this.jodb2Completed = true)),
  this.job3().pipe(tap((result3) => this.jodb3Completed = true)),
])
.subscribe(response => {
  finalJob();
  console.log('done', respone)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With `finalize`, for example. Or `tap`, if you want things to happen on every emission *(edit: and/or if you are interested in the emitted values)*, not on completion (and if that makes any difference).

```
const stream1$ = this.job1().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.jodb1Completed = true)
);

const stream2$ = this.job1().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.jodb2Completed = true)
);

forkJoin([stream1$, stream2$]).subscribe(this.finalJob);
```

Comment: `finalize` doesn't pass any value e.g. `result` as far as I know

Comment: @Drenai you're right. I corrected my answer.